# How to set up your path so you can call 'julia' via the Terminal?

Tags: unix, path, exec, julia

This is more of a n00b Unix question regarding how to set up paths correctly. It is also not a question that is specific to `julia`, but rather how to set up paths correctly in general (I suspect).

At the moment, the only way I can start `julia` via the Terminal is by using the command:

`$ exec '/Applications/Julia-0.4.0.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia'`

rather than `$ julia`

How can I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change to your home directory and find the file `.bash_profile` (note the `.` at the start: this is a hidden file. You can do `ls -a` to see if it is there, or just try to open it with an editor.)
2. Create the `.bash_profile` file if it doesn't already exist (e.g. using your favourite text editor).
3. Add the following line somewhere:

   ```
   alias julia="/Applications/Julia-0.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia"
   ```
4. Open a new terminal window and enjoy!

(Note that 0.4.1 is the current latest stable version, which is what I have used here.)

Comment: Thanks for all the Julia help! BTW, how do I consistently update julia? Homebrew/macports has made me a lazy pythonista

Comment: By "consistently", I mean I think with the above method I have to update my `.bash_profile` file for each update. Which is ok, if that's what I must do.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang you can checkout a release version, build it from source, and then `ln -s /bin/local/julia /your/julia/repo/julia`(only once). this is "consistently" but time consuming.

Comment: Is there a way to get regular updates of the new releases via e-mail? I believe I have joined the google group