# How to run Julia script and function from terminal?

Tags: terminal, julia

I'm learning the Julia language and followed some tutorials to test OLS (ordinary least squares) estimation in Julia. First, I need to simulate a dataset of dependent variable ("Y"), independent variables ("X") ,error terms (epsilon) and parameters. The script is like:

```
# ols_simulate ：generate necessary data
using Distributions
N=100000
K=3
genX = MvNormal(eye(K))
X = rand(genX,N)
X = X'
X_noconstant = X
constant = ones(N)
X = [constant X]

genEpsilon = Normal(0, 1)
epsilon    = rand(genEpsilon,N)
trueParams = [0.1,0.5,-0.3,0.]
Y = X*trueParams + epsilon
```

and then I defined an OLS function

```
function OLSestimator(y,x)
    estimate = inv(x'*x)*(x'*y)
    return estimate
end
```

What I planed to do is first to simulate data from terminal with command:

```
ols_simulate
```

and hope this step generates and stores data properly, and then I could call `olsestimator` . But after trying this, when I typed `mean(Y)` in Julia REPL, it gives me an error message like

```
Error: UnderdefvarError: Y not defined
```

it seems the data are not stored properly. More generally, if I have multiple scripts (scripts and function), how can I use the data generated by one from others in the terminal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each time you run the Julia REPL (the Julia "command-line"), it begins with a fresh memory workspace. Thus, to define variables and then use them, you should run the interpreter once.

If I understand correctly, you have multiple scripts which do parts of the calculations. To run a script in the REPL and stay in it with all the global variables still defined, you can use

```
include("scriptname.jl")
```

(with `scriptname` changed to appropriate `.jl` filename).

In this case, the workflow could look like:

```
include("ols_simulate.jl")
estimate = OLSestimator(Y,X)
mean(Y)
```

In general, it's best to stay in the REPL, unless you want to clear everything and start fresh and then quitting and restarting is the way to go.

Comment: the `include` trick works, thank you. One more question, should I save the function script with **arbitrary** filename (say `OLSestimator.jl`) to the current dictionary and then call it from REAL. That's what I did but it turned out to be another **undefined error**. The availiable example about Julia function are mostly with command line function, my question boil down to "how to call function?"

Comment: It's a little hard to understand your question. I presume, "dictionary" should be "directory" and "REAL" should be "REPL". Still, being a little clearer about what you are actually doing and seeing would help. If you get an error, please quote the whole error message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the script in a separate file and then load it into Julia. Say you already saved it with name "ols_simulate.jl" in directory "dir1", then navigate to that directory in the Terminal, startup Julia (you might want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849556/how-to-set-up-your-path-so-you-can-call-julia-via-the-terminal)). Once in Julia, you have to load "ols_simulate.jl", after which you can calculate the mean of `Y` and do whatever you want:

```
include("ols_simulate.jl")
mean(Y)
OLSestimator(Y, X)
```

For the kind of stuff that I think you are doing, I think you could find useful using a notebook interface like [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org).